# Javascript - If condition is met, return True for specific amount of time, then false

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, timer

I'm trying to code a function that, if some conditions are met, it returns "true" for some time, then return false again, even if the condition is still true.

The idea of the code is something like this:

```
if(condition is met)
    {return 'True' for 3000ms then 'false'} //even if the condition it's still 'true'
        else {False}
```

I can easily program the result of the condition (returning true or false if met), but i'm having a lot trouble trying to (if true) returning it for a specific amount of time.

NOTE: a function with setTimeout() is not an option in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346503/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use closure for this scenario

```
function falseReturnAfter(time) {
    let val = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        val = false;
    }, time);
    return function(con) {
        if(con && val) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
let f = falseReturnAfter(10000) // return false after 10 sec.
f(true) // true
f(false) // false
// after 10 sec
f(true) // false
f(false) // false
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: @kavigun it does - executing the returned function after the time runs out will flip the result.